# slickgrid and contextmenu

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, slickgrid

Due to the bad performance of the jquery datatable (very slow in loading a large number of records) I've replace it with slickgrid, it has amazing speed in loading huge number of records, however I have the below questions:

How I can enable the context menu on left click and hide on mouseleave?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at Slickgrid example 7.

From the example:

You first create a context menu using an unordered list in HTML.

Add the relevant styles to your CSS file.

Create the JQuery event handlers in JavaScript file.